# Stored procedures to check date for example i want to check first whether start date is larger than expiry date then only i want to execute query

Tags: sql-server

Table passenger

```
create table passenger
(
    passport_no varchar(15) not null,
    fname varchar(25) not null,
    minit char(1),
    lname varchar(25) not null,
    gender char(1) not null,
    nationalty varchar(50) not null,
    dob date not null,
    issue_of_pport date not null,
    exp_of_pport date not null,
    catagory varchar(10) not null,
    acc_pport_no varchar(15),

    constraint pk_passenger primary key (passport_no),
    constraint fk_gauardian_passenger 
        foreign key (acc_pport_no) references passenger(passport_no),                   //****//
    constraint check_catagory 
        check (catagory='adult' or catagory='senior' or catagory='child' or catagory='infant'),
    constraint chech_gender_passenger 
        check (gender = 'm' or gender = 'f')
)
```

My stored procedure

```
create or alter procedure find_passport_expiry_date
    (@passport_id varchar(50),
     @no_of_days int output)
as
begin
    select @no_of_days = datediff(day, issue_of_pport, exp_of_pport) 
    from passenger 
    where passport_no = @no_of_days
end

declare @days int
exec find_passport_expiry_date '43fafea',@days output
select @days as 'no_of_days_until_expiry'
```

Comment: What is your question?   Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below

```
    create or alter procedure find_passport_expiry_date
     (@passport_id varchar(50),
     @no_of_days int output)
  as
 begin
      select @no_of_days = datediff(day, issue_of_pport, exp_of_pport) 
      from passenger 
      where passport_no = @passport_id 
end
if @no_of_days >0 
 exec find_passport_expiry_date '43fafea',@days output
```